# Jquery CSSlider loading gif freeze....not loading the plugin slideshow?

Tags: jquery

I have recently installed a Jquery plugin which I purchased onto my web server but when I try running the plugin on my page it just freezes on the loading gif image.....I have checked all paths to css, Jquery, images etc... and just can't seem to find the problem I  decided after beating my brains for about 4 hours I need help, so I'm hoping someone here can resolve my problem. a link to my website - [Please view code here](http://www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk/index2.html)

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console it is viewing the error

"$ is not defined"

This means the jQuery library is not, or not correctly included.

Hope that helps.

Comment: as I am looking to your code, the Problem is that you include jQuery at the bottom, you have to include it before the first use of $

Comment: Ok, thanks Tobias, could this be the link to the original jquery plugin, Oh..strange I got told to add the link to the jquery just before the last </body> tag as this makes it load quicker ?

Comment: This will just let the other content loaded faster, but if you add it in head tag this is no problem and solves your issue.

Comment: You could move the code wich loads the Plugin behind the <script src="jquery.js"> etc..

Comment: Hi Tobias I have moved all the script stuff to the top of the html before the style section and still no joy?? could you re-visit my web page and see what you think the issue could be ? it's driving me insane :D

Comment: You call it with $('slider').ccsli[..]; this would mean the following html code:
<slider></slider>
But you have a div with an id, so you have to use:
$('#slider').ccslider({[...]

Comment: Ahhh thanks Tobias, I got so carried away correcting the other code I completely forgot that the slider had a Div ID lol!! thanks again all is working well now :)

Comment: No Problem (: Nice I could help you.